# MariaDB, is there a way for alter a query before his execution?

Tags: mariadb

I have some web applications connected to MariaDB.
I can't modify the code of these applications but I want run some scripts when theses applications query the database.

Example : if the application A add certain values in his database, I want add certain values in an another database used by the application B

There are two approach (maybe more ?) :

- 1) I "catch" the query submitted to MariaDB and do some operations
- 2) Or a script read periodically the database and do some operations

I think the fist way is the best approach..but I don't now if its possible to do that.
What's the best solution and how can I do that ?

Thank you !

Comment: See [MariaDB MaxScale :: Filter Plugin](https://mariadb.com/products/mariadb-maxscale/how-maxscale-works).

Comment: Thanks :) can you give me more informations ? Im a mariaDB beginner and my english isn't very good...

Answer (score 1):

A `TRIGGER` (MariaDB or MySQL) can be invoked to perform operations when a *write* operation occurs.  You specify whether it is `INSERT` or `UPDATE`, etc, and what table is involved.

`cron` or MariaDB/MySQL `EVENT` can periodically do something.

The "query rewrite" feature "catches the query and allows for changing it before being submitted.  It is available in MySQL 5.7, but not MariaDB.

Would you care to explain what you are trying to do.